# RCP plug-ins communication

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, communication, rcp

How can two independent plug-ins of a RCP application communicate (exchange data and messages) without setting dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

you can use OSGi Event Admin mechanism: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-event-admin.html or http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2011/01/03/enhanced-rcp-how-views-can-communicate